# Declarative Markup: Expression Builder

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to display the value of `MyClass.SomeMessage` in the expression builder `<%$  $>` of the label control below?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" 
     Text="<%$ Is there a way to display the value of MyClass.SomeMessage here %>" />

public static class MyClass
{
    public static string SomeMessage
    {
        get
        {
            string message = "This is some test message";
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It there a real reason this is a serverside label?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="<%$ Is there a way to display the value of MyClass.SomeMessage here %>" />
```

If yes, then change `<%$` to `<%#` use `lblMessage.Databind()` on the server side and you can see the value there.

Since it's a label, I would suggest using some html client side value and use `"<%=MyClass.SomeMessage %>"`. You must not have the runat server though.

Comment: I will give it a try later today.